# Dúvida POO Javascript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Estou praticando POO em JavaScript e, procurando alguns exemplos na internet, me deparei com a prática abaixo:

```js
function Product(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    //this.discount = 0; // <- remove this line and refactor with the code below
    var _discount; // private member
    Object.defineProperty(this, "discount", {
        get: function () { return _discount; },
        set: function (value) { _discount = value; if (_discount > 80) _discount = 80; }
    });
}

//  the client code
var sneakers = new Product("Sneakers", 20);
sneakers.discount = 50; // 50, setter is called
sneakers.discount += 20; // 70, setter is called
sneakers.discount += 20; // 80, not 90!
console.log(sneakers.discount); // getter is called
```

Eu refiz o exemplo sem olhar pra ele e funcionou numa boa.

No entanto, quando tentei uma abordagem diferente para o mesmo exemplo, eu já me perdi um pouco.

O que eu tentei fazer foi ao invés de definir uma nova propriedade usando o método 'defineProperty' dentro da função construtora, definir externamente, como se eu fosse implementar essa propriedade um tempo depois.

Só que o log está dando 'undefined'.

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Estou praticando POO há pouco tempo.

Segue a diferente abordagem que tentei:

```js
function Product(name, price) {
    this.name = name; 
    this.price = price;
    var _discount;
}

Object.defineProperty(Product, 'discount', {
    get: function () {
        return this._discount;
    },
    set: function (value) {
        _discount = value;
        if (_discount > 80) {
            _discount = 80;
        }
    }
})

var television = new Product('samsung_a3045', 1000);

television.discount += 50;
console.log(television.discount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa ter em mente que em JavaScript algumas coisas são diferentes da maioria das linguagens que trabalham com OO. As propriedades são membros definidos **diretamente nos objetos** e não nas classes como seria em outras linguagens.

Por isso, o primeiro parâmetro de [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) é o **objeto** onde a propriedade será definida, não uma definição de classe. Na sua tentativa, ao invés de passar o objeto você passa a função que define a classe.

No exemplo abaixo, o **objeto `a`** contém a propriedade `discount`, já o **objeto `b`** não.

```js
function Product(name) {
    this.name = name
}

var a = new Product('Teste 1')
var b = new Product('Teste 1')

Object.defineProperty(a, 'discount', {
    get: function () {
        return 'TESTE' 
    }
})

console.log(a.discount)
console.log(b.discount)
```

Comment: E se eu quiser 'exportar' essa nova propriedade para outro objeto que possui a mesma base construtora? Ou seja, outro objeto criado com a função 'Product'?

Comment: @LucasStellet Você faz como no seu primeiro exemplo. Lá o defineProperty será executado para todos os objetos que forem criados...

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! :)